# Monitoring Databricks usage Cost

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I want to give my users access to an inbuilt  shared Databricks cluster which they can spin up and use to run their query over a table. I would like to know as an admin how will I know which user ran the cluster and for how long , so that I can bill them accordingly. How we can do that here? also is there a way that i can configure so that multiple user can run their notebooks using the same cluster and none gets blocked by other

Answer (score 0):

To give users access to an inbuilt shared Databricks cluster.
Here are the below steps

1. In the Admin Settings you can create a Group. In the group you add
   Users or even you can give access to the SPN.

[image]
**Add Users:**
[image]

2. In the Shared Cluster Configuration page you can provide
   permissions: The below would be the permission you can see from the
   dropdown:

   **

- **Can Attach** The "Can Attach" permission allows users to attach to a Databricks cluster and use its compute resources for executing their queries and running jobs.
- **Can Manage** The "Can Manage" permission is not directly relevant to the ability to spin up and use a Databricks cluster or run queries over a table. The "Can Manage" permission is primarily associated with managing workspace-level resources, such as managing users, groups, and workspace settings.
- **Can Restart** The "Can Restart" permission in Databricks specifically grants users the ability to restart a Databricks cluster. It does not provide the permission to run queries over tables or perform any other data access or manipulation operations.

**"Can Attach"** permission on clusters: This permission allows users to attach notebooks to Databricks clusters, which is necessary to run the code in the notebooks.

**"Can Read" or "Can Write"** will be enabled when the users are given  the **Can Attach** permission.
To run queries over tables or access data in Databricks, users typically require additional permissions such as **"Can Read" or "Can Write"** on the specific tables or databases

[image]
Once you have added the users **CONFIRM and RESTART** the Cluster to apply the recent changes.

Once the Cluster is Up and running in the cluster configuration
page navigate to Event Log you will see able.
Time and user name.
[image]

Know More about [Creating Clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure)

The read, edit,manage,and can be done at the permissoion level.

Comment: it doesn't answer the question - it's not about creating a cluster, but how to collect the costs of using that cluster

Comment: @AlexOtt let me edit the solution and post it

Comment: and where is CAN READ and CAN WRITE permission, I dont see that.. can you provide that screen shot along with the cost part

Comment: @The read, edit,manage,and can be done at the permissoion level.